# Function to get a specified parameter from a POJO class

Tags: java, frameworks, java-8

Using java I want to create a function whose input is a query (like XPath) and output is the specified parameter in the class (example given below), is there a framework I can use to get similar results.

Example:-
Need to write the code for the function **String getParams(String, List< Topic >)**

```
package temp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Temp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Topic> topics = new ArrayList<Topic>();
        topics.add(new Topic("XYZ", "XYZ-param1", "XYZ-param2", 123, null));
        topics.add(new Topic("ABC", "ABC-param1", "ABC-param2", 234, null));

        List<Subscription> subs = new ArrayList();
        subs.add(new Subscription("subs1", "subs1-param1", 701, null));
        topics.add(new Topic("123", "123-param1", "123-param2", 234, subs));

        String input1 = "/topics/{name = XYZ}/";
        String input2 = "/topics/{name = ABC}/param1/";
        String input3 = "/topics/{name = 123}/subs/{name = subs1}/param2";
        // If a topic with name XYZ is present in the list (topics), should return a string (json format) containing members of class Topic
        getParams(input1, topics); // output - "{"name":"XYZ", "param1":"XYZ-param1", "param2":"XYZ-param2","param3":"123", []}"
        // If a topic with name ABC is present in the list (topics), should return a param1.toString of that class Topic
        getParams(input2, topics); // output - "ABC-param1" 
        // If a topic with name 123 is present in the list (topics) and a subscription with name subs1 is present in the topics subscription list, should return a param2.toString of that class Subscription
        getParams(input3, topics); // output - "701"
    }

    public class Consumer {
        public Consumer() {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
        public String name;
        public double param1;
    }

    public class Subscription {
        public Subscription(String name, String param1, int param2, List<Consumer> consumers) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.param1 = param1;
            this.param2 = param2;
            this.consumers = consumers;
        }
        public String name;
        public String param1;
        public int param2;
        public List<Consumer> consumers;
    }

    public class Topic {
        public Topic(String name, String param1, String param2, long param3, List<Subscription> subs) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.param1 = param1;
            this.param2 = param2;
            this.param3 = param3;
            this.subs = subs;
        }
        public String name;
        public String param1;
        public String param2;
        public long param3;
        public List<Subscription> subs;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not introducing methods like: `findByName(String name)` or `getAllSubscriptionsByName(String name)`?

Comment: If your actual classes are valid Java Beans, you may want to look into using `java.beans.Introspector` for obtaining and matching object properties. Also, suggestion: your "path" looks a lot like XPath format to me, except for "attribute matcher" pattern. If you change that pattern, this might open you to use numerous XPath-processing libraries out there.

Comment: If they aren't Java Beans (your example has public fields), then just use reflection and parse queries as you like. You seem to have already defined what "matching" looks like and what "property access" looks like